# Why reassign functions inside Scheme let?

Tags: scheme

This is code from *Simply Scheme* (code [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch27/appendix-simply.html)) which the student is supposed to load and use as we follow along with the exercises. (Note: I'm an individual doing this for myself only.)

```
(define first
  (let ((pair? pair?)
    (char->word char->word)
    (string-ref string-ref)`
    (word->string word->string)
    (car car)
    (empty? empty?)
    (whoops whoops)
    (word? word?))
    (define (word-first wd)
      (char->word (string-ref (word->string wd) 0)))
    (lambda (x)
      (cond ((pair? x) (car x))
        ((empty? x) (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x))
        ((word? x) (word-first x))
        (else (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x))))))
```

I'm well enough along to understand the general use of `let` and `lambda` in this function, but what I don't understand is why in the `let` form each supporting function (some homemade, some batteries-included Scheme) are being repeated, e.g., `(pair? pair?)` and `(car car)`. Why are these being quasi-reassigned inside this `let`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is designed for use as "library code" in a variety of Scheme implementations, including ones where built-in bindings could be redefined. The `let`s ensure that the original bindings will be used in the library functions, even if the user redefines the top-level bindings later on.

For non-library code that you write, you will generally not have to worry about that. Also, if you're using a Scheme implementation with a module system that enforces immutable module bindings (such as Racket), that won't be a concern either.